# How to find mount point for audio CD/DVD

Tags: mount

Ok, I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I am unable to find the mount point for my CD/DVD. I inserted a CD in the rom, and I see the files just fine in nautilus, but when I try to run the following command

sudo mount -l

it gives me all the mount points, except one for the CD. I looked in "/mnt/" folder and there are no subfolders. "/media/" folder has a folder name cdrom but is empty and doesn't seem to be mounted. So where exactly is my CD mounted? I also cannot find anything that looks like a CDROM device name in "/dev/".

Comment: Is it an audio CD by any chance?

Comment: Yes indeed, I googled and found that the deal with the audio CD's is a bit differently. How do I deal with audio CD's then? This was really puzzling to me as I had never seen the mount point so amazingly absent from the mount listings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Audio CDs are a bit different - there's no actual filesystem there and as such they can't be mounted. Gnome's gvfs subsystem (which stands for "virtual filesystem") provides a file-like view of tracks on the audio CD, but it does it by directly accessing the device, without actually mounting it. So the tracks on the Audio CD look like files, but in fact they're not. They don't have real filenames, file size in bytes or other attributes of normal files.

You can convert those tracks to normal .mp3 or .ogg files using CD-ripping software if you need.

The "mount points" for gvfs (though they're not real mount points) are created in `~/.gvfs` folder. There's supposedly also `gvfs-mount` command which can list/manage the mounts

Googling for "gvfs cdda" will provide you with additional information if you're still curious.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response, yeah, it did seem like gvfs had something to do with it.