# How to change GVFS mount point?

Tags: gvfs

There is a way to change the GVFS mount point which by default is "~/.gvfs/" ?
And by the way how to change the name of mounted folders which by default is "my folder on myserver.tld" ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  The accepted answer to this question may help you  http://askubuntu.com/questions/102406/how-to-find-mount-point-for-audio-cd-dvd

Comment: Is there any peculiar reason for another mount point?

Comment: Thanks for your answers:
Stephen Myall : This answer just say that the mount point is ~/.gvfs
Takkat : Beacaus .gvfs is hidden folder and non-GTK app can't access to gnome shortcuts (so we have to search for the mount point to access Samba shared folders)

Comment: You may be fine with [smbnetfs](http://askubuntu.com/a/24376/3940) then.

Comment: Maybe a hardlink?

Comment: Can't hardlink folders bro

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as per this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/61196/why-do-my-gvfs-mounts-not-show-up-under-gvfs-or-run-user-login-gvfs after Ubuntu 12.10 the mount point was moved to: /run/user/(your username)/gvfs/sftp\:host\=\192.168.xxx.xxx indicating this question from 2012 was about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL and off-topic. OP hasn't signed on since 2012 either.