# How can I use an ISO of an audio CD?

Tags: mount, cd

I have an ISO of an audio CD that was created by someone using OS X. I would like to use this ISO in Ubuntu -- ultimately in order to extract the tracks to sound files.

When I attempt to mount the ISO, I get the following message:

```
>sudo mount -o loop ~/CD.iso /home/user/cdmount
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

How should I do this?

Comment: What if you do `sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ...` or `sudo mount -t udf -o ...`? ISO9660 and UDF are the most common filesystem types for CD/DVD images.

Comment: @muru Hey there. Thanks for your help on this. When I use either `iso9660` or `udf`, it presents me with a "wrong fs type" message.

Comment: You coul try `-t auto`, but audio CDs normally do not have filesystems...

Comment: Please edit your post to add the output of `file -k ~/CD.iso`.

Comment: @muru It responds simply with "data", which I guess means that it doesn't recognise it. Would it be possible that OS X is doing something strange to the image? The command used to create the ISO on OS X was `sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk2; dd if=/dev/disk2 of=~/CD.iso bs=2048 conv=sync,notrunc`.

Comment: @fkraiem Thanks for that thought. What would be a good approach to effectively converting the audio CD ISO to a set of audio files?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. Audio CDs do not have filesystems, so it is impossible to mount this image. Stricly speaking, it is not even an ISO image at all (because it is not an image of an ISO9660 filesystem), just a raw data dump.

Comment: Ehm I would asssume you insert CD and use a ripping program?

Comment: @fkraiem Audio CDs are interpreted somehow such that the computer can extract audio from them. I have an ISO image of an audio CD. Surely there must be some way to get Ubuntu to read from the image rather than from an inserted audio CD volume. Would you have any thoughts?

Comment: It's plausible that there could be some way to do that, yes, but I don't know of any.

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't have a CD drive, so I got someone with a MacBook running OS X to make an ISO image of the audio CD. I have the ISO and I'm now trying to find how to extract the audio from it.

Comment: You can't make an iso of an audio cd.  You can make a raw image file plus a .cue sheet that describes the tracks.  Do you have the .cue sheet?

Comment: dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/102406/how-to-find-mount-point-for-audio-cd-dvd

Comment: Curios, what does `file` say about the image. Also try `7z t <filename>`.

Answer (score 4):

Audio CDs do not have file systems for tracks. It is raw data burned to the disc.

What you have isn't an ISO but raw data of the disc. You cannot mount it.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that. My goal is to extract the audio tracks from this ISO image of the audio CD. Would you have any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to play an audio CD rip (from Nero, many many years ago) with this:

`mplayer -demuxer rawaudio my_audio_cd_rip.nrg`

or

`mpv -demuxer=rawaudio my_audio_cd_rip.nrg`

or (after changing the file extension)

`play -r 44100 -e signed -b 16 -c 2 -L my_audio_cd_rip.cdda`

and to convert it to an MP3:

`sox -r 44100 -e signed -b 16 -c 2 -L my_audio_cd_rip.cdda -C 320 my_audio_cd_rip.mp3`